# Cannot boot to elementary OS, boots to UEFI instead

Tags: release-freya, boot, uefi

On my Asus X301A I have only Elementary OS Freya installed. Everything was great but at some point of time it started to boot to Aptio Setup Utility which is UEFI on my laptop, as far as I understand. So it boots there almost all the time, but sometimes I reload and it boots normally to elementary OS.

I tried Boot-Repair tool several times, after one 'repair' it seemed that it was finally fixed, as laptop booted normally for some time, but then I installed some updates and it started again...

Here is one of my boot-info summaries: http://paste2.org/m52Mt48U

Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: Did you install grub on the EFI partition? Or also on your data partition (to me the file you posted looks like you did)? My experience so far is that it works perfectly well if you just install grub on the EFI partition. Googling around you sometimes find older instructions that tell you to install grub on your system partition, but I don't think that is necessary anymore. Since 0.3.2, freya shouldn't have any problems with UEFI anymore, either

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
efibootmgr
sudo efibootmgr -o XXXX,YYYY,ZZZZ
```

Where XXXX, YYYY, ZZZZ..... are the ids you got with the fist command

If elementary OS is your only OS why you have the Windows boot loader?
You could delete it

```
cp -r /boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft ./backup #If you want backup it. Recomended
sudo rm -rf /boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft
```